Connection to eduroam fails
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and have the config for eduroam from my university. Sometimes it works, but very often (lately) I cannot connect. It loads and fails.
This is the log for the NetworkManager from the time I click connect to the time it fails and stops loading:
Sep 10 17:05:01 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955501.5897] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:05:01 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955501.5949] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:05:01 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955501.5950] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955524.4528] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955524.4528] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955524.4531] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955524.4534] device (wlp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'eduroam'
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955524.4536] device (wlp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955524.4742] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:05:24 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955524.4742] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5912] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'eduroam' (46458d6d-de99-4360-ae48-a1411d5b5242)
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5913] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="46458d6d-de99-4360-ae48-a1411d5b5242" name="eduroam" pid=43700 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5914] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5917] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5920] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5923] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'eduroam' has security, but secrets are required.
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5923] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5954] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5957] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5964] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5996] Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5997] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5997] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5997] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384 WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'eap' value 'TTLS'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=PAP'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/me/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'identity' value '<hidden-from-forum>'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5998] Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value '<hidden-from-forum>'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.5999] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.6162] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 10 17:11:04 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955864.6163] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 10 17:11:06 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955866.5647] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 10 17:11:06 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955866.5648] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 10 17:11:06 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955866.5746] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:11:06 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955866.5746] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:11:06 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955866.5846] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:11:06 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955866.5847] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955889.4498] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4499] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955889.4503] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4514] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4517] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4535] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4684] Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4685] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4685] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4685] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384 WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4685] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4685] Config: added 'eap' value 'TTLS'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4686] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4686] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=PAP'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4686] Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/me/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4686] Config: added 'identity' value '<hidden-from-forum>'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4686] Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value '<hidden-from-forum>'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4686] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4732] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4732] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4816] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 10 17:11:29 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955889.4817] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 10 17:11:31 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955891.5593] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 10 17:11:31 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955891.5594] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 10 17:11:31 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955891.5715] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:11:31 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955891.5715] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:11:31 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955891.5790] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:11:31 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955891.5790] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955914.4508] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4509] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955914.4514] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4532] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4535] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4538] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'eduroam' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4677] Config: added 'ssid' value 'eduroam'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4678] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4678] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4678] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP FT-EAP FT-EAP-SHA384 WPA-EAP-SHA256'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4678] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'eap' value 'TTLS'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=PAP'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/me/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'identity' value '<hidden-from-forum>'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'anonymous_identity' value '<hidden-from-forum>'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4679] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4733] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4733] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4819] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 10 17:11:54 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955914.4819] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 10 17:11:56 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955916.8069] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 10 17:11:56 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955916.8069] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 10 17:11:56 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955916.8159] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:11:56 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955916.8159] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 10 17:11:56 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955916.8261] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:11:56 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955916.8262] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955939.4519] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955939.4520] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955939.4523] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <warn>  [1725955939.4526] device (wlp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'eduroam'
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955939.4529] device (wlp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955939.4698] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Sep 10 17:12:19 X1C NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1725955939.4698] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected

[Of course, some personal information is redacted from this log for privacy reasons.]
I do not know if it's relevant or not, but I am using OpenVPN (which I am by default not connected to).

EDIT: Eduroam worked on my laptop in the neighbouring building (dormitory) the same evening. Could it be the way the routers are configured? I assumed not, since my phone was connected all day without issues.

Have you always used the VPN and being able to connect? Or was it working when you were not using the VPN?

VPN was one of the first things I configured when I installed the OS, so I don't know what it would have been without. Also, (supposedly) the same connection (i.e. eduroam) worked on my laptop in the dormitory yesterday evening, but it did not work at the lecture hall. [My mobile phone was connected all the time.]

Did you figure it out? If you found a solution consider answering your own question. This will help others.
